# Obtaining the point at which drag-and-drop gesture is dropped

Tags: user-interface, drag-and-drop, javafx-2

I think this should be really easy with JavaFX - so I must be missing the point somewhere.  I have a simple drag-and-drop from a toolbar onto an AnchorPane which works fine, however I'm trying to find out exactly where the drop occurs to find out where to insert the new item within a group of Nodes already there.  The event object DragEvent tells you the target object but not where it was dropped relative to the target ( only relative to the source ).  I tried just listening to all mouse released events on the target but that isn't triggered for a drag onto an object.  Anyone know how this should be done?

Mike Watts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the `getSceneX/Y` methods to obtain absolute coordinates of the location of the drop or install a listener on the AnchorPane which listens to DRAG_OVER DragEvents. The last position of the DRAG_OVER event that occured before it was dropped is the position where it was dropped.

Comment: Thanks for that Sebastian - yes I was confused by all the references to the 'source's scene' but that works nicely: `targetPane.sceneToLocal(ev.getSceneX(), ev.getSceneY())` returns the point in the target pane ( where ev is the DragEvent object and targetPane is cast from ev.getTarget() )

Comment: i totally forgot about that method, yes. i'm glad that it works now.